# Include not working with join entities

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-core

As example I have following entities (many-to-many, I also removed unnessecary props):

```
public class Buffet
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

public class Recipe
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int CategoryId {get; set;}
    public virtual Category Category {get; set;}
}

public class Category
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

Join entity:

```
public class BuffetRecipe
{
    public int BuffetId {get; set;}
    public virtual Buffet Buffet {get; set;}
    public int RecipeId {get; set;}
    public virtual Recipe Recipe {get; set;}
}
```

I want to get all recipes that belong to a specific buffet and want include the recipe category.

```
public IList<Recipe> GetRecipes(int buffetId)
{
    return _dbContext.BuffetRecipes
    .Where(item => item.BuffetId == buffetId)
    .Include(item => item.Recipe)
    .ThenInclude(item => item.Category)
    .Select(item => item.Recipe)
    .ToList();
}
```

The list I get always returns Recipes with prop Category = null.
I didn't find a solution to make the Include() work together with the Select()...

What am I doing wrong??

UPDATE:

I can make it work this way... but my feeling says this is not a good way because i have 2 ToList() calls... but now I have category included in my results:

```
public IList<Recipe> GetRecipes(int buffetId)
{
    return _dbContext.BuffetRecipes
    .Where(item => item.BuffetId == buffetId)
    .Include(item => item.Recipe)
    .ThenInclude(item => item.Category)
    .ToList()
    .Select(item => item.Recipe)
    .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing it with the `BuffetRecipe` class instead of collections on both `Buffet` and `Recipe`? You lose the ability to travel between the two. Your `BuffetRecipe` class will be created as a table you don't need in C# to manage that many to many relationship.

Comment: In EF core there is no many-to-many without join entity... So I have to manually create a BuffetRecipe entity to make this kind of relation work in the new EF core...

Comment: I only want to add that the include is working without the Select in the end. Is this by design?

Comment: `Include` only works if you don't return a projection `.Select(item => item.Recipe)`. You should start the query with `_dbContext.Recipes`.

Comment: okey thanks for that info... can you help me with a linq query which achieves what i want?

Answer (score 4):

`Include` is only effective if it can be applied to the end result of the query.

You *could* change it into ...

```
return _dbContext.BuffetRecipes
    .Where(item => item.BuffetId == buffetId)
    .Select(item => item.Recipe)
    .Include(rcp => rcp.Category)
    .ToList()
```

... but the drawback of this is that you duplicate your `Recipe`s (as many as they have `BuffetRecipes`). It's better to start the query with `Recipe`:

```
return _dbContext.Recipes
    .Where(rcp => rcp.BuffetRecipes.Any(br => br.BuffetId == buffetId))
    .Include(rcp => rcp.Category)
    .ToList();
```

You see that I took the liberty to add a navigation property `Recipe.BuffetRecipes`. This shouldn't be any problem with your model (on the contrary, I'd say).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback... but I have to tell you that your first query does not work... meaning it does not include the category... even if I put the include after the Select().

Comment: Your second query results in SQL like:

SELECT xxxxxxxxxx FROM [Recipes] AS [item]
INNER JOIN [RecipeCategories] AS [r] ON [item].[CategoryId] = [r].[Id]
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM [BuffetRecipes] AS [br]
    WHERE ([br].[BuffetId] = @__buffetId_0) AND ([item].[Id] = [br].[RecipeId]))

which looks not very good to me :-(

Comment: That's the query I would expect. As for the first query, you never can tall what works with EF core, unfortunately, but as I said, I don't like the query anyway.