# NULL Subcollections in framework, OK in LINQPad

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, aspnetboilerplate

i have this inherited SQL view code that I converted to linq to get some data out in the meantime, in LINQPad it works as expected, but upon transferring it to my c# solution, the subcollections are not loaded.

```cs
  var query = from poh in _pckOrderHeadeRepository.GetAllIncluding(pd => pd.PckOrderDetail)
                join mcs in _mstrConsigneeShipToRepository.GetAll() on poh.RouteId equals mcs.Consignee
        //select new {poh, mcs}; //works
        join det in (
            from d in _pckOrderDetailRepository.GetAllIncluding(pd=> pd.PckOrderHeader, pd => pd.MstrSku)
            join s in (
                from shpCartonHeader in _shpCartonHeaderRepository.GetAll()
                group shpCartonHeader by new
                {
                    shpCartonHeader.OrderNum
                }
                into g
                select new
                {
                    g.Key.OrderNum,
                    CartonWeight = g.Sum(p => p.TotalWeight)
                }) on d.PckOrderHeader.OrderNum equals s.OrderNum into sJoin
            from s in sJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
            group new {d.PckOrderHeader, d, d.MstrSku, s} by new
            {
                d.PckOrderHeader.OrderNum
            }
            into g
            select new
            {
                g.Key.OrderNum,
                OrderQty = g.Sum(p => p.d.OrderQty),         
                OrderWeightOpen = (decimal?)g.Where(p => p.d.PckOrderHeader.OrderStat.Equals("OPEN")).Sum(p => p.d.MstrSku.Weight * p.d.OrderQty),
                OrderWeightReleased = (decimal?)g.Where(p => p.d.PckOrderHeader.OrderStat.Equals("RELEASED")).Sum(p => p.d.MstrSku.Weight * p.d.PickingQty + p.s.CartonWeight),
                 OrderWeightPacked = (decimal?)g.Where(p => p.d.PckOrderHeader.OrderStat.Equals("PACKED")).Sum(p => p.s.CartonWeight),
                PrePack = g.Max(p => p.d.MstrSku.Prepack)
            }) on poh.OrderNum equals det.OrderNum
        join toa in _shpTrailerOrderAssignmentRepository.GetAll() on poh.OrderNum equals toa.OrderNum into
        toaJoin
        from toa in toaJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()

        select new
        {
            det,
            poh,
            toa,
            mcs
        };
```

this part in particular:

```
 select new
            {
                g.Key.OrderNum,
                OrderQty = g.Sum(p => p.d.OrderQty),         
                OrderWeightOpen = (decimal?)g.Where(p => p.d.PckOrderHeader.OrderStat.Equals("OPEN")).Sum(p => p.d.MstrSku.Weight * p.d.OrderQty),
                OrderWeightReleased = (decimal?)g.Where(p => p.d.PckOrderHeader.OrderStat.Equals("RELEASED")).Sum(p => p.d.MstrSku.Weight * p.d.PickingQty + p.s.CartonWeight),
                OrderWeightPacked = (decimal?)g.Where(p => p.d.PckOrderHeader.OrderStat.Equals("PACKED")).Sum(p => p.s.CartonWeight),
                PrePack = g.Max(p => p.d.MstrSku.Prepack)
            }) on poh.OrderNum equals det.OrderNum
```

for example this:

```
PrePack = g.Max(p => p.d.MstrSku.Prepack) // MstrSku is not loaded
```

and the property inside p.d (PckOrderDetail)

```
public virtual MstrSku MstrSku { get; set; }
```

the equivalent query in linqpad works correctly, so im wondering what am I missing to properly load the sub properties to mimic LINQPads behaviour.

Comment: Is this EF Core?

Comment: yes it is EFCore 2.0.1 , ASPNET Zero 4.6.0.0

Comment: It's a limitation of EF Core: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40380621/include-not-working-with-join-entities

Comment: i see, do i have to load the collection in that select statement then? will be an ugly query...

Comment: Well, it's already ugly.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use p.d.MstrSku.Prepack then you have to include it in the outer table. when you include it in joined table you cannot select.

use it in the first line like the sample below

```
.Include(x => x.OrderDetails.Select(y => y.MstrSku)).ToList();
```